# ¿De dónde viene usar "capón" para referirse a un golpe en la cabeza?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, dle

Ayer, buscando información para otra pregunta, acabé consultando la definición de "**capón**":

> **[capón<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=7LE519L)**.
>   **Del lat. vulg. **cappo***, por *capo, -ōnis*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un hombre o de un animal: castrado. U. t. c. s. m.
> 2. m. Pollo que se castra cuando es pequeño, y se ceba para comerlo.
> 3. m. Haz de sarmientos.
> 4. m. Mar. Cadena o cabo grueso, firme en la serviola, que sirve para tener suspendida el ancla por el arganeo.
> 5. m. rur. Cuba. Retoño que nace en la planta de tabaco después del primer corte.
>
> **[capón<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=7LEhkBl)**.
>   **Del lat. vulg. **cappo***, -ōnis.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Golpe dado en la cabeza con el nudillo del dedo corazón.

Lo que me sorprendió no fue que tuviera esas acepciones, sino el hecho de que para la acepción relativa a "golpe en la cabeza" se indique como origen el latín *cappo*, que al fin y al cabo es la misma raíz que se indica para todas las demás acepciones y que quiere decir "pollo castrado y cebado".

**¿Cómo una palabra para denominar a un "pollo castrado y cebado", acabó significando "golpe en la cabeza con los nudillos"?**

Y ya que estamos, ¿por qué aparecen como entradas separadas en el DLE, si el origen etimológico es el mismo?

Comment: Date cuenta que la primera acepción, según el DLE, no viene de _cappo_ sino de _capo_, y la segunda sí viene de _cappo_. No sé si esa breve distinción hace que ambas sean etimologías diferentes.

Comment: Pues ni idea, he buscado en DidacTerion, pero no me aparece "capo" como palabra latina, ni tampoco "cappo". Igual en otros diccionarios...

Comment: Nótese que las formas citadas del LV son hipotéticas (de ahí el asterisco \*). ¿Significa *capón* lo mismo que *coscorrón*? Quizá sea onomatopéyico-expresivo.

Comment: *Capo* en italiano es cabeza, supongo que derivado de *caput*. ¿Podía haber derivado un signficado de *cappo* y otro de *caput*?

Comment: @pablodf76 si, aquí en Colombia ese golpe en la cabeza dado con el nudillo del dedo del corazón lo llamamos _coscorrón_

Comment: Etimologías de Chile da una explicación parecida a mi suposición: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?capo.n. Parece que las dos vienen del latín *cappo* pero con dos origenes distintos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la web de *Etimologías*, [se corrobora lo que dice el DLE](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?capo.n):

> La otra palabra capón que significa golpe dado en la cabeza con el puño cerrado y los nudillos, se considera que procede de un latín vulgar **cappo*, vinculado al vocablo latino *caput* (cabeza), que se asocia a una raíz indoeuropea **kaput-* del mismo significado.

En la web dice que la etimología es diferente de la otra definición, que vendría de *capo, caponis* (gallo castrado).

He estado buscando usos de la palabra con este sentido, pero no he encontrado gran cosa. Me temo que podamos estar ante otra palabra cuyo significado coloquial ("golpe en la cabeza") existió ya hace siglos pero se consideraba vulgar. Al tener otra acepción más culta, la vulgar no se registró.

Vamos marcha atrás. En el CORDE el caso más antiguo que encuentro es este:

> *— [...] Y descolgar ese retrato.
>
>   —¿El del abuelo?
>
>   —El del abuelo; pues no me gusta verle tan cejijunto, con los bigotes tan crecidos, y esos ojos tan fieros que se diría que va a descender de la altura para atizarnos un capón.*
>
> Salvador González Anaya, "La oración de la Tarde", 1929 (España).

Visto así parecería que es una creación reciente, pero buceando por los miles de documentos que contienen la palabra "capón" en la hemeroteca del BNE, he podido encontrar algunos con la acepción que nos interesa.

> Quiso al punto la ofensa desquitar
>   el secretario, y le soltó un capon;
>   en esto que el alcalde alzó el bastón
>   y al sindico el capon le fué á parar.
>
> **[Almanaque de la risa.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003372725&page=114&search=cap%C3%B3n&lang=es)** 1/1/1880, página 114.

Y yendo más atrás, este es el más antiguo caso localizado (os pongo el párrafo entero que no tiene desperdicio):

> **Atención**. Palabras que tienen un sentido
>   aparente y otro verdadero.
>   *Una muchacha á su novio.* —¡Fastidioso! (¡Adorable!)
>   *Un obispo.* —¡Unidad religiosa! (¡Mis seis mil duros!)
>   *Un deudor á su acreedor.* —Vuelvo. (Las espaldas.)
>   *Un mozo de café.* —¡Allá voy! (¡Espérame sentado!)
>   *Un dómine á un escolar travieso.* —Vén, chiquitín. (Te daré un capón.)
>   *Carlos VII.* —¡Queridos españoles! (Como me dejéis meter el hocico...)
>   *Isabel* á sus ex-súbditos. —¡Adiós, hermosos!
>
> **[La Iberia (Madrid. 1868).](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001291099&page=3&search=%22un%20cap%C3%B3n%22&lang=es)** 12/2/1869, página 3.

Nótese que en este caso de 1869 no se pone la palabra en cursiva, ni se añade explicación, por lo que se entiende que el sentido del "golpe" era de sobra conocido ya por entonces. Y tan de sobra conocida era, como que en el *Diccionario de autoridades* (tomo 1, de 1729) ya venía esa acepción:

> El golpe que se dá en la cabéza à otro con la coyuntura del dedo de enmedio, lo que es mui comun en los muchachos.

Y cita un texto que he identificado como escrito en 1670:

> *En cuyo hermoso cabello
>
>   arto (por cierto) dorado
>
>   diò alguna palmada Midas,
>
>   algun capon, ò sopapo.*
>
> Melchor Alegre, "[Delicias de Apolo, recreaciones del Parnaso, por las tres Musas](https://books.google.es/books?id=VEBpAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA36&lpg=RA1-PA36&dq=%22en%20cuyo%20hermoso%20cabello%22&source=bl&ots=Ot-HdYXJrW&sig=dQ3UgbD2BLbFjszjiGR-uI-KDwk&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA4M-2y__YAhUC2KQKHa6iCM4Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22en%20cuyo%20hermoso%20cabello%22&f=false)", 1670 (España).

Pero espera, que cuando ya pensaba que no iba a llegar más atrás, me encuentro con que el diccionario español-latín de Nebrija de 1495... ¡incluye la acepción! En este se lee:

> Capon ave castrada. capo.onis.capus.i
>   Capon golpe del dedo. talitrum.i

Así que con esto creo que ya hemos dado con la respuesta. Definitivamente no creo que la acepción como "ave castrada" haya dado origen a la del golpe, sino que ambos significados convivieron desde antiguo, cada uno con su etimología diferente.

---

En este paseo por la historia echaba en falta una definición de nuestro amigo Covarrubias, dado que la palabra debía existir en su época (su diccionario es de 1611). Tras buscarla un poco encuentro que, aunque no viene la entrada "capon", tras la definición de "capar" y completamente fuera del orden alfabético viene lo siguiente (escritura adaptada):

> CAPONES de ceniza: los golpes que dan en la frente con un trapo atado, lleno por de dentro de ceniza menuda: esto es en pena de los yerros que se cometen en algunos juegos, que por entretenimiento suele hazerse entre donzellas y gente moça las noches de fiesta en Invierno, especialmente por Navidad. Dixeronse capones â capite, porque se dan en la frente.

Comment: @walen según la fuente, la acepción de "ave castrada" la derivan de _capo_ o de _cappo_, parece que no hay consenso. Pero definitivamente es una palabra diferente a _cappo_ como "cabeza".

Answer (score 2):

Puede tener relación con el catalán *cap*:

[Diccionario catalán-español](https://es.glosbe.com/ca/es/cap)

> - cabeza
>   - frente

Comment: ¿Será que "ón"  da la idea de golpe como en coscorrón o pescozón?